# Sulfuric acid symmetry point group

Tags: crystal-structure, symmetry, crystallography

On the following page: https://cccbdb.nist.gov/pglist.asp It appears that the point symmetry group of sulphuric acid is $C_2$. I know that $C_2$ means that there is an axis of symmetry of order 2 (180 degree rotation).
But, I am not able to visualize it in the molecule.

[image: Sulphuric acid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact, you can see $C_2$ and other symmetry elements for yourself in 3D by opening the CIF [[1](https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270196006749), [COD-2005680](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/2005680.html)] with [Mercury](https://www.ccdc.cam.ac.uk/solutions/csd-system/components/mercury/) (free, available for Windows, Linux, MacOS):

[image: Unit cell of crystalline sulfuric acid]

**Figure 1.**
Unit cell of crystalline sulfuric acid $\ce{H2SO4}$.
Green lines parallel to crystallographic axis $b$ depict $C_2$ rotation axes.

This can be achieved by drawing the unit cell content with *Calculate → Packing/Slicing…*  and adding symmetry elements of interest via *Display → Symmetry Elements…*.

[image: C2 axis and a molecule of H2SO4]

**Figure 2.**
Single molecular unit $\ce{H2SO4}$ in two projections with the $C_2$ placed in drawing plane (left) and perpendicular to drawing plane (right).

#### References

1. Kemnitz, E.; Werner, C.; Trojanov, S. Reinvestigation of Crystalline Sulfuric Acid and Oxonium Hydrogensulfate. *Acta Crystallographica Section C Crystal Structure Communications* **1996**, 52 (11), 2665–2668. https://doi.org/10.1107/S0108270196006749.

Comment: How I can a draw the molecule on Mercury? @andseliskç

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar I updated the answer with the [link to CIF](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/2005680.html), which you can open with Mercury. This is an experimentally determined structure which you are not supposed to "draw" yourself.

Comment: I do everything you tell me and I don't get what you get.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar What exactly you are experiencing problems with?

Comment: First of all, it is still not clear to me where I can find more molecules (such as water, benzene, ammonia,...). Also, once I open the sulphuric acid file in Mercury and pulse the "Packing/..." command I don't get the same thing that you hung in your answer. And, if I add the symmetry, numerous planes and lines appear, nothing to do with what you put.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar 1. The question was solely about sulfuric acid. If you want other structures, search the [COD](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/search.html) yourself. 2. You are supposed to *choose* what area you want packed by ticking *Pack* box and selecting the coefficients for each axis $a$, $b$ and $c$ (I used defaults 1). 3. As I said, add symmetry elements *of interest*: read what each element stands for in that dialogue windows, and deselect those you don't want to see.

Comment: Okey, thanks. And, last but not least, how did you get the last images? That is, a single molecule with its elements of symmetry.

Comment: @aprendiendo-a-programar No prob. **Figure 2** is a compilation of two screenshots of a single molecule depicted in Mercury along two separate crystallographic axes which I added a "$C_2$" label in [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/) (image editor) to. I decide to do so for clarity for those users who won't bother opening the structure in Mercury:)

Comment: It's just that I'm currently learning the punctual symmetry of molecules and I'm new at this. And, a question, is Mercury able to predict the elements of symmetry in the molecule? Because I've seen this option and I don't know if it's the right one:

Display < More Information < Symmetry Operator List...

By the way, I have searched in the page that you told me the ammonia (drawing its structure in the option that there is for it) and it doesn't come out. What do you usually do to search in that database for molecules?

Comment: Mercury is just a viewer (and certain functions are not available in free version), and it just takes the symmetry info from the CIF. However, Mercury is probably the best crystallographic tool for the beginners I ever encountered (the rest is even more cumbersome or costs money). As for ammonia, [here is one](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/2310927.html) I found by adding "H3" and "N" to "*1 to 8 elements*" field and "2" and "2" to "*number of distinct elements min and max*" ([search hints](http://www.crystallography.net/cod/tips.html)). Unfortunately, no COD structures have H assigned.

Comment: And apart from this program, would you recommend any other to appreciate the elements of symmetry? Sometimes I do them, and I have no way of knowing if it's okay. Because, for example, with the sulphuric acid in the tables on the internet I knew it was C2 and I didn't know where it was. So, what would you recommend me for? Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to have a look at online tutorials such as [Chemtube3d/Symmetry](http://www.chemtube3d.com/SymHOME.htm) and [Symmetry@Otterbein](http://symmetry.otterbein.edu/). Both offer similar 3D interactivity via JSmol, a JavaScript library for crystal structures, a desktop alternative to which is [Jmol](http://jmol.sourceforge.net/). You can also search Chemistry.SE (this site), I remember even I answered a couple of similar/related questions before.

Answer (score 2):

In the structure as drawn here, the axis is perpenducular to the plane of the paper passing through the sulfur atom.

Comment: But, if I turn around that axis, every 180 degrees the molecule would not be as it was initially. @Oscar Lanzi

Comment: Which atoms would be out of place?  Look again... .